Package not found
I have installt my ros2 workspace, than I have build a package and in the package I have build Nodes, at the beginning the all ar working prpoerly.
But since a fiew days I the consol shows „package my_robot_controller not found“ (my_robot_controller is the name of my pachage. I dont knew what I hade done wrong, that it now dont work.
How can I make it run like it was at the beginning.
My configuration is: „ros2_ws/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller/„name of the node““.
I am using Iron.
If I am going forward with „cd“ and „ls“ I come to the nodes, but if I use ros2 run my_robot_controller it dosn work.

Could you please delete ros2_ws/build ros2_ws/install and ros2_ws/log directories and run cd ros2_ws && colcon build? Once you source install/setup.bash afterwards, try to see if the terminal auto-completes your package-name by using tab. Pay attention to the errors showing up while building, too!

How can I delete ros2_ws/build?

by opening your terminal and going into your workspace i.e. cd whateveryourpathis/ros2_ws and then in that workspace directory you type rm -r build log install.

I have deleted build, install and log and tryed the steps you write my bat unfortunately it dosǹ´t work. Here is the terminal:                                                                      samy@ros:~$ cd ros2_ws && colcon build
[0.407s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_identification:ROS package 'my_robot_controller' in 'src/my_robot_controller' has more than one build type
Starting >>> my_robot_controller
Finished <<< my_robot_controller [1.02s]
Summary: 1 package finished [1.67s]
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$ install/setup.bash
bash: install/setup.bash: Keine Berechtigung

samy@ros:~/ros2_ws$ cd src
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src$ cd my_robot_controller
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller$ my_robot_controller
my_robot_controller: Befehl nicht gefunden.
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller$ cd my_robot_controller
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ ls
chatgpt_quadrat.py  my_first_node.py    pycache
draw_circle.py      my_test_node.py     sicherheits_kopie.py
init.py         pose_subscriber.py  turtle_controller.py

usage: ros2 run [-h] [--prefix PREFIX] package_name executable_name ...
ros2 run: error: the following arguments are required: executable_name, argv
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ install/setup.bash
bash: install/setup.bash: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
samy@ros:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$

Look into this guide on how to format comments/questions/answers and edit your comments.
